# Retaining object created by a class method?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

This is probably something I should know by now, I am creating an instance of NSTimer using the NSTimer class method. I am pretty sure the returned object is autoreleased, my question is in terms of memory management should I be then retaining and releasing the timer object (**METHOD: 1**), or simply just assigning it directly to the @property (**METHOD: 2**)(or should I be doing something totally different?)

```
// METHOD: 1
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *myTimer;
```

.

```
NSTimer *tempTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0 target:self selector:@selector(executeOnTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [self setMyTimer:tempTimer];
    //[tempTimer release];
```

.

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [pulseTimer release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

OR SIMPLY:

```
// METHOD: 2
myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0 target:self selector:@selector(executeOnTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

## EDIT:

One final point, if I just write (see below) without assigning to a property is there any chance that the timer is going to get deallocated, basically does it stay around until the program exits. Just curious how its retained?

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:120.0 target:self selector:@selector(executeOnTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Comment: The `NSTimer` has a special consideration. `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval...` message not only initiates the timer but also adds it to the runloop. That prevents `NSTimer` to be released and you should invoke `invalidate` method in order to take back ownership from the run-loop internals. More about [-(void) invalidate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTimer/invalidate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to take ownership over the NSTimer you can do one of these with the same effect:

```
self.myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: ...]; // implicit setter
```

or

```
[self setMyTimer: [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:...]]; // explicit setter
```

or

```
myTimer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: ...] retain];
```

or

```
self->myTimer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: ...] retain];
```

Comment: You are retaining myTimer twice in the second example and thus you should release it once.

Comment: @Time Machine: in first example I wrote the same as [self setMyTimer: [NSTimer...]]; So, only once. No `release` if you still need a reference to NSTimer

Comment: @Time Machine sorry, but the second has exactly the same effect as the first :)

Comment: Ooh I taught you had two examples: line 1 and 3, and line 5 and 7. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the good way:

```
self.myTimer = tempTimer;
// don't call [tempTimer release]
```

This will retain it automcailcally due to the property which retains it.

Just calling `myTimer = …` doesn't use the setter while `self.myTimer = …` does.

Comment: Epic spelling fail. Stupid tiny iPod keyboard.

Comment: Note that this is equal to METHOD 1 without the release message.

Comment: My mistake, I don't need the release as I don't own the timer (i.e. there is no alloc). My property retains the timer when set with either [self setMyTimer:tempTimer]; or self.myTimer = tempTimer; that retain is balanced out with the release in the dealloc.